# How old is Steven Universe?

Tags: age, steven-universe

Steven is portrayed as being quite young, but I can't place his exact *biological* age. What confuses me is that he seems much younger than Connie who is portrayed as his peer.

All I could find is this:

> Steven's exact age has not yet been confirmed. It was confirmed by Matt Burnett that we might not find out for a while. [citation needed]

~[SU wiki](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Universe_(character))

With no clue as to if that is a stale quote, and not being able to watch all the episodes through, I can't tell if this has actually been revealed yet.

I know he can affect his *apparent* age, with his mental state<sup>1</sup>.

How old is Steven?

<sub>1. [*So Many Birthdays*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/So_Many_Birthdays)</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of "Too Far" (episode 73, 2015-10-15, last episode of 2015), Steven's age has not been stated in any episode, and the creators of the show give deliberate non-answers whenever asked.  The most recent confirmation of unconfirmedness I can find is [an August 4 tweet](https://twitter.com/ianjq/status/628770934887813121) from [Ian Jones-Quartey](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Ian_Jones-Quartey):

> > If you don't mind me asking, how old are Steven and Connie? About how old is Greg now and when he first met Rose?
>
> you may find out in an upcoming episode!

UPDATE: "Steven's Birthday" (episode 75, 2016-01-05) depicts Steven celebrating his

> fourteenth

birthday.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would spoiler-tag the birthday number, since that's the answer to this question.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: I spoiler-tagged it because it's a spoiler.  It's even a spoiler to one of the characters in the episode!

Comment: In normal circumstances maybe. However, if someone is viewing the question "How old is Steven", I'm not sure if spoiler-tagging his age is needed.

Comment: is it a spoiler or just unknown information up until that episode? Ie - does the 'mystery' of his age in any way relate to the series lore or plot or is it just trivia that ultimately bears no weight to the overall story?

Comment: @NKCampbell It's definitely an unexpected reveal that relates to the lore and his powers - until this point the audience is subtly led to believe Steven is much younger than this.

Answer (score 2):

In the episode "[Steven's Birthday](https://steven-universe.fandom.com/wiki/Steven%27s_Birthday)", he turns 14. Connie is revealed to be 13, only 4 months younger than Steven. Before that, he was 13 so was Connie probably also 13. He stays 14 until *[Steven Universe: The Movie](https://steven-universe.fandom.com/wiki/Steven_Universe:_The_Movie)*, where he is briefly announced in the beginning as being 16. I'm assuming four months has passed since he turned 16, so I'll just say Connie is 16 too, which he stays for the rest of the series ending in the episode future.

Answer (score -3):

This is purely hypothetical but I would assume Steven Universe is 19 now due to reading this.

> The 14-year-old youngest member of the Crystal Gems. A unique being, Steven is the first and only known Gem–human hybrid, the product of the union between the Crystal Gems' original leader, Rose Quartz (formerly known as Pink Diamond), and Greg Universe, a human musician and car-wash owner.
>
> First appearance: *Pilot (2013)*, *"Gem Glow" (2013)* (main series)
>
> [Steven Universe (character)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Universe_(character))

Comment: Age progression doesn't work the same way in fiction than it does in real life. If a character was 14 when they were introduced, and there's no explicit mention of the passage of time, you can safely assume they're still 14.

Comment: Especially in cartoons.  Bart Simpson has been in fourth grade for 30-odd years.  Even for an underachiever, that's a long time.